# Possible reasons for HTML5/WebRTC video being rendered too small within its container?

Tags: android, html5-video, webrtc

What are possible reasons that a video might be rendered as shown in the below screenshot? There's supposed to be a fullscreen video container rendering a remote peer's video in a WebRTC chat. There's a smaller inlay for the local video in the lower left. The `<video>` container does fill the entire size it's supposed to, but it is largely filled with green, with the actual video rendered small and distorted in its upper left corner. The video is supposed to fill the entire green space. The green colour *is* the video, it's a rendering artefact, it is not my styling.

I have had *occasional success* getting it to render full screen, but more often than not the video clings to the corner. No code changes between success and failure, just trying again and again. This is running on an Android 4.4.2 tablet, tried both Opera and Chrome. Works fine on desktop browsers.

Looking for any hints as to what may cause this and how one could fix it or work around it.

[image: Incorrectly rendered video]

Comment: Same behavior if the orientation is landscape?

Comment: Yup. Though in landscape, the aspect ratio of the tiny video is correct. Looks like it's getting squished from its original landscape into portrait aspect ratio when in portrait.

Comment: FWIW, this *appears* to be an entirely uncontrollable bug, maybe video driver related or something. I have tried about a dozen variations on how to draw the video and the behaviour randomly appears and disappears. Works fine on an Android 5.0 device. Still, if anyone knows anything...

Answer (score 1):

This problem is indeed as you already found a problem with the video driver in combination with hardware decoding of the videostream within Chrome. It can be fixed on the device by disabling the hardware videodecoding for webrtc in the chrome://flags. The option text is a bit fuzzy, since you need to enable the disabling of video decoding in order for the hw video decoding to be disabled. I hope there will be a better solution soon.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that this is a graphics driver related bug and nothing that can be fixed in the browser. It simply won't work. (For the record: ASUS Memo Pad 8.)

One possible workaround for the really desperate: hide the actual video, render the video on a `<canvas>`, traverse from the top-right towards the top-left until you find non-green pixels, do the same bottom-left to top-left, use the discovered offsets to crop the video on the canvas. This will be super slow and ugly, but is a desperate fix if you need it. I haven't coded this yet, but I might if necessary.